# Управление HTML JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

Как в JavaScript вывести на страницу "Ожидаете...", Потом стереть этот текст и загрузить основной HTML код, без перехода между страницами?

Comment: Вы хотите SPA реализовать?

Comment: Если это так называется, то да

Comment: Просто из описание вопроса, не очень понятно что именно нужно...

Comment: но если нужно SPA (Single Page Application) смотрите в сторону Vue.js, Angular, React

Comment: Если я в <head> размещу document.write("Ожидайте..."), то как потом удалить "Ожидайте...", чтобы прогрузился основной код?

Comment: добавил код в ответе

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`document.write("<div class='loader'>Ожидайте...</div>")`
и этот код чтобы удалился `.loader` после загрузки

```
window.onload = function() {
  var loader = document.querySelector('.loader');
  loader.remove();
};
```

Comment: Сначало появляется Ожидайте... потом сразу появляется основной текст, и Ожидайте... не удаляется

Comment: А основной текст откуда берётся?

Comment: Уже разобрался, спасибо.

Answer (score 2):

```js
$.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1', {}, function (data) {
  $('#loading').css('display', 'none')
  $('#result').text('Результат: ' + data.title)
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="loading">
  Загрузка...
</div>
<div id="result">

</div>
```